# Spring: SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type

Tags: spring, jdbc

I was trying to insert an employee using `JdbcTemplate`. But I am getting `Invalid Column Type` exception. Any idea what could be the issue?

---

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into employees (employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,hire_date,job_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?))]; SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
        at com.spring.EmployeeDAOImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:46)
        at com.spring.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:33)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9168)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8749)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9471)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9454)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:816)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
        ... 5 more
```

---

Here are the entire files which I have created.

*Employee.java*

```
package com.spring;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Employee {

    private Integer employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private Date hireDate;
    private String jobId;

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Date getHireDate() {
        return hireDate;
    }
    public void setHireDate(Date hireDate) {
        this.hireDate = hireDate;
    }
    public String getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }
    public void setJobId(String jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }

}
```

EmployeeDAO Interface

```
package com.spring;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException;

public interface EmployeeDAO {

    void setDataSource(DataSource datasource);  
    void addEmployee() throws MetaDataAccessException;

}
```

---

EmployeeDAOImpl.java

```
package com.spring;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException;

public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;   
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void addEmployee() throws MetaDataAccessException{

        String databaseName = (String)JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource, "getDatabaseProductName");
        String databaseVersion = (String)JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource, "getDatabaseProductVersion");
        String driverName = (String)JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource, "getDriverName");
        String driverVersion = (String)JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource, "getDriverVersion");
        System.out.println("Database Name: " + databaseName);
        System.out.println("Database Version: " + databaseVersion);
        System.out.println("Driver Name: " + driverName);
        System.out.println("Driver Version: " + driverVersion);

        String sql = "insert into employees (employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,hire_date,job_id) values"
                                            + " (?,?,?,?,?,?)";


        Date date = new Date();

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(2007),"AAAAAAA","BBBBBB","abc@gmail.com",new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()),"ST_MAN"}, new EmployeeMapper());



    }
}
```

EmployeeMapper.java

```
package com.spring;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper<Employee>{
    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmployeeId(rs.getInt("employee_id"));
        employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
        employee.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
        employee.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        employee.setHireDate(rs.getDate("hire_date"));
        employee.setJobId(rs.getString("job_id"));

        return employee;
    }
}
```

spring.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"></property>
            <property name="username" value="hr"></property>
            <property name="password" value="welcome"></property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="employeeDAOImpl" class="com.spring.EmployeeDAOImpl">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.spring;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException;


public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MetaDataAccessException{
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        EmployeeDAOImpl dao = (EmployeeDAOImpl)context.getBean("employeeDAOImpl");
        dao.addEmployee();

    }   

}
```

Output :

```
Database Name: Oracle
Database Version: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Driver Name: Oracle JDBC driver
Driver Version: 10.2.0.1.0
May 19, 2014 7:51:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
May 19, 2014 7:51:30 PM org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory <init>
INFO: SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into employees (employee_id,first_name,last_name,email,hire_date,job_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
    at com.spring.EmployeeDAOImpl.addEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:38)
    at com.spring.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:30)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8749)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9471)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9454)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:816)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: You should post the code that produced this exception in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: Posted all the files which are involved in this task.

Comment: it can be enum type  that needs to converted first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[],%20int[])), the third parameter must be "SQL types of the arguments (constants from `java.sql.Types`)" but you have provided `new EmployeeMapper()`.

Comment: removed the extra trailing ")" but still facing the same issue

Comment: Please update the stack trace after your change. Also make sure to edit your code change above that you made too so that we all have the full picture in your OP.

Comment: Here is the stack trace after removing the extra trailing ")"

Comment: Replaced the old stack trace with new one

Comment: Thanks jordan. I don't need third parameter.
It worked after removing the third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

for me this issue happened when i try to set null value on timestamp column. I changed the value timestamp(0). This seems to me a driver issue. I was using oracle 10g / ojdbc14.jar / oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

```
?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)


java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
at  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.get_internal_type(OracleStatement.java:6433)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNull(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1354)
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing new EmployeeMapper()

```
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(2007),"AAAAAAA","BBBBBB","abc@gmail.com",new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()),"ST_MAN"});
```